# Breezejs typescript promise has no fail method in definition file

Tags: javascript, typescript, breeze, q

I am working on a project where im using breezejs to talk to my webapi.
I have setup a simple register form with which i can register a new user:

```js
public addUser(user: IApiUser): void {
    this.dataContext.entityManager.addEntity(this.dataContext.entityManager.createEntity("ApiUserEntity", user));
}
```

To write the added entity the the webapi i am calling the saveChanges() method on my entitymanager in breezejs:

```js
// Save any changes for this datacontext
return this.dataContext.entityManager.saveChanges().then((saveResult: breeze.SaveResult): breeze.SaveResult => {
    return saveResult;
});
```

I have downloaded the typescript definition file for breezejs from [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2d4c4679bc2b509f27435a4f9da5e2de11258571/breeze/breeze.d.ts) 
, but looking at the saveChanges signature:

```js
 saveChanges(entities?: Entity[], saveOptions?: SaveOptions, callback?: SaveChangesSuccessCallback, errorCallback?: SaveChangesErrorCallback): breeze.promises.IPromise<SaveResult>;
```

It returns a promise of type:

```js
breeze.promises.IPromise<SaveResult>;
```

Now when i inspect the IPromise in the definition file i get the following interface:

```js
interface IPromise<T> {
    then<U>(onFulfill: (value: T) => U, onReject?: (reason: any) => U): IPromise<U>;
    then<U>(onFulfill: (value: T) => IPromise<U>, onReject?: (reason: any) => U): IPromise<U>;
    then<U>(onFulfill: (value: T) => U, onReject?: (reason: any) => IPromise<U>): IPromise<U>;
    then<U>(onFulfill: (value: T) => IPromise<U>, onReject?: (reason: any) => IPromise<U>): IPromise<U>;
    catch<U>(onRejected: (reason: any) => U): IPromise<U>;
    catch<U>(onRejected: (reason: any) => IPromise<U>): IPromise<U>;
    finally(finallyCallback: () => any): IPromise<T>;
}
```

And i just dont understand why they chose to implement it like this. I am using the Q.js library which has a fail and a .done method etc but if i type these my typescript files wont compile because the interface does not recognize these methods.

[image]

I have looked for specific definition files for breeze with Q.js but they dont seem to exist. Offcourse i can just edit the definition file but i would like to know what the reason is for setting it up like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fail` is just a synonym  for `catch`, that works in old browsers. `catch` works in all modern browsers. Also EcmaScript 6 have native [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with `catch` method.

You can declare missing methods somewhere in your code:

```
interface IPromise<T> {
    fail<U>(onRejected: (reason: any) => U): IPromise<U>;
    fail<U>(onRejected: (reason: any) => IPromise<U>): IPromise<U>;
}
```

This declarations will be [merged](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Declaration%20Merging.md) with declarations from original `.d.ts`.